# React Native - Android app working on Debug, crashing on Release

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm using React Native v0.19, and when running on Android my app works just fine on Debug, but immediately crashes when I run it in Release mode, or from the signed release apk. Android Studio throws an error:

```
02-01 13:16:40.650 12399-12424/? E/ReactNativeJS: undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.propTypes.style')
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug that happens because two classes were moved to another package on version v0.19 of React Native: `ReactProp` `ReactPropGroup`. To fix this error, open your `proguard-rules.pro` and edit the following lines:

```
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactProp <methods>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactPropGroup <methods>; }
```

for:

```
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp <methods>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactPropGroup <methods>; }
```

Reference:

- [[Android]Release crash "s.propTypes.style" #5655](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5655#issuecomment-178896957)