# Android app working fine in debug mode but crashing in release mode

Tags: android, react-native

Android app working fine in debug mode but crashing in release mode
- My gradle file and the only diff b/w prev version and current version is added firebase, firebase core, messaging

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ctdapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Android app working fine in debug mode but crashing in release mode
- My gradle file and the only diff b/w prev version and current version is added firebase, firebase core, messaging

Comment: Add Crashlytics, and then check the crash message.

Comment: Much more likely because of proguard.

Comment: what does the crash log say?

Comment: @Azhar92 nothing it just closes the app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native - Android app working on Debug, crashing on Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422246/react-native-android-app-working-on-debug-crashing-on-release)

Answer (score 0):

try this code :
add

```
dependencies 
{
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}

android {
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 21 
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...
}
```

chnage in manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp">
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
    ...
</application>
</manifest>
```

or add add    MultiDex.install(this); to MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! it was related to this

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22046#issuecomment-435320495